# BlueImp FileUpload, Azure Blobs, and WebKit

Tags: file-upload, azure, blob, jquery-file-upload

When I upload to Azure, the file in cloud storage receives the following header:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarybzJFMKUkIyKi8fb4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="yif_2.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<file data stuff>

------WebKitFormBoundary2HGRqdPKdw6QiYNB--
```

I also receive `unexpected end of input` when uploading these files.

Then, when I download them, they are unreadable -- presumably because of these issues.

I am using BlueImp's file upload to handle multi-uploads/chunking/drag&drop/etc.

EDIT: I mean I think it's because I am not using a server to handle the upload, so instead of the form data being parsed appropriately, it is uploading the entire form -- could somebody tell me how to extract the data then in Javascript, perhaps?? If that's the issue at all

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being twofold -- first, I used the File API to read in the content to a buffer -- second, I had to delete options.headers provided in the FileUploader script